# quickblox Sample-videochat-android is not working (Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError)

Tags: android, quickblox, videochat

http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-videochat-android

I want to test quickblox's voicechat sample app.

However, I'm getting on this error.

```
11-08 17:55:40.321: E/AndroidRuntime(14889): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
11-08 17:55:40.321: E/AndroidRuntime(14889):    at com.quickblox.module.videochat.core.AudioRecorder$AudioRecorderRunnable.run(AudioRecorder.java:116)
11-08 17:55:40.321: E/AndroidRuntime(14889):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-08 17:55:40.321: E/AndroidRuntime(14889): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load ilbc-codec: findLibrary returned null
11-08 17:55:40.321: E/AndroidRuntime(14889):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
11-08 17:55:40.321: E/AndroidRuntime(14889):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
11-08 17:55:40.321: E/AndroidRuntime(14889):    at com.googlecode.androidilbc.Codec.<init>(Codec.java:16)
11-08 17:55:40.321: E/AndroidRuntime(14889):    at com.googlecode.androidilbc.Codec.<clinit>(Codec.java:5)
11-08 17:55:40.321: E/AndroidRuntime(14889):    ... 2 more
```

Please, help me!!

Comment: please try again, there are a couple of new commits here https://github.com/QuickBlox/Sample-VideoChat-android

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error...

Funny thing is, if you try and debug the app, it actually brought me to the next screen (with the 2 buttons Audio Call and Video Call). What I did is I put a break point in class ActivityCallUser on the line: QBVideoChatService.getService().setQBVideoChatListener(currentQbUser, qbVideoChatListener);

Run in debug mode and then once it hit the break point, press F6 (Eclipse) to step over, until the black screen is replaced with the 2-buttons screen, then you can skip. What happened next is I can try debugging with 2 phones following the exact steps and make calls to each others... though I can't hear anything from both phones and i can't see video footage of either phones.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `libilbc-codec.so` library. , this occurs when the library is not included properly.
You can do the following steps to resolve this problem !

1. When android looks for the `.so` libraries they need to be in the lib (NOT libs) directory (this caused me problems initially). Remember, this is a native library and native code needs to be in the lib directory not libs.
2. After you have .so file create a `.zip` dile from the lib directory ( you can name it as `native-libs.zip` ). You should now have a `.zip` with `lib/armeabi/**.so` as the contents. And now rename the extension of the `.zip` to `.jar` giving you the file name as `native-libs.jar`. And then drag the jar into your android studio project libs or library with other directory(same location as all your other jar libraries).
   And make sure to right click on the native-libs jar and add it as a library.
3. Finally, add this to your projects build.gradle:

Compile fileTree(dir: ‘libs’, include: ‘*.jar’)
and make sure all the compile fileTree and compile project are also present with native.jar in dependencies if you have so.

Eg. :

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: '../jar', include: '*.jar')

    compile project(':pull-to-refresh')

    compile files('libraries/native-libs.jar')
}
```

Hope this Helps :)

Comment: I got video call but on oppenent side camera not display. and also issue in voice, voice disturbunce and voice delay by 10 to 15 seconds... how to solve this issue???